# PlantUML: Unexpected result with "Arrows from/to class members"

Tags: uml, plantuml

I'm trying to do something similar to this:
[image]

The only differences I have with my code are my classes are formatted with a dot, like `auth.Permission`:

```
@startuml
class auth.Permission {
+ id
+ content_type
+ codename
}


class auth.Group {
+ id
+ name
+ permissions
}

auth.Group::permissions -- auth.Permission
@enduml
```

As you can see, the end result is wrong: a third class is created instead of drawing the relation at the right place: https://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/uml/SoWkIImgAStDuKhEIImkLaWiBSdG2qWjoiqiBixCprEevj9Mo4m14idvUIMfUINn9PK5gM1kIcfUOcugLoqN5x9MzwByqWA4Bf0I85K0Dx0Of06XqieAIKf1LnVTVYw7rBmKeEi0

[image: wrong output]

What I'm doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: As per UML this is not defined. It would be a non-standard extension (I know that Enterprise Architect supports it in its own way).

Comment: @qwerty_so any workaround?

Comment: Maybe use `::` instead of `.`?

Comment: @albert Doing this works but removes the automatic packages inclusion (all classes automatically bordered with `auth` legend). I tried to add `set namespaceSeparator ::` but then, a third class is created again :(

Answer (score 6):

A bit long for a comment, but how about:

```
@startuml
package auth {
class Permission {
+ id
+ content_type
+ codename
}


class Group {
+ id
+ name
+ permissions
}

Group::permissions -- Permission

}
@enduml
```

giving:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I thought of this solution, but was expecting to benefit from the "automatic packaging" feature (not just to be picky, but just because using `package` would require a big rework in my software which generates the puml file)

Comment: I can imagine that it might be a bit of a rework for you. As the original feature was not working and previously you asked for a possible workaround ... ( ;-) )

Comment: yes, thanks again :) I was secretly hopping I made some syntax mistake somewhere haha.